# Conditional Statments in c++

Tags: c++

I am interested in executing a statement at the end of an if-statement block, but it seem I cannot do so. Is there a way to do it? 
For example:

```
int x = 0;
if (x > -1) {
cout << "I" << endl;
else if(x > -2)
cout <<"hope" <<endl;
cout <<"this works" << endl;
}
```

I am hoping to print out "I hope this works."  The statement "this works" is not apart of the else if statement but apart of the if statement (x > -1)

Comment: Your code should not compile: the 'else' has not a matching 'if'

Answer (score 6):

That is not how an else if statement works. In this case, you would want something like this

```
int x = 0;
if (x > -1) {
  cout << "I" << endl;
  if(x > -2){
    cout <<"hope" <<endl;
  }
  cout <<"this works" << endl;
}
```

[Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html) is some information on if...else statements in c++. `else if` needs to be used *after* an if statement (you put it inside of it). `else if` will only run if the previous `if/else if` statements did not run and if the condition is met.

Comment: there is no need of condition `if x > -2` , if `x > -1` then obviously `x` is greater than `-2`

Comment: Obviously it doesn't make sense logically, but the OP seems to just be playing around with conditional statements, i don't think his program is supposed to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;
if (x > -1) 
{
    cout << "I" << endl;
    cout <<"hope" <<endl;
    cout <<"this works" << endl;
}
```

elseif is generally used in chaining if - else. You can read a tutorial online on elseif

Answer (score 0):

after seeing your code , there is no need of two `if` conditions for your requirements i.e printing `i hope this works`

it can be either

```
int x = 0;
if (x > -1) {
  cout << "I" << endl;
  cout <<"hope" <<endl;
  cout <<"this works" << endl;
}
```

or this

```
int x = 0;
if (x > -2) {
  cout << "I" << endl;
  cout <<"hope" <<endl;
  cout <<"this works" << endl;
}
```

but this doesn't make sense as `if x > -1 , then obviously x > -2`

```
 int x = 0;
if (x > -1) {
  cout << "I" << endl;
 if(x > -2){
  cout <<"hope" <<endl;
 }
  cout <<"this works" << endl;
}
```